# Run inline script after loading async resources

Tags: javascript

I tested my page with an optimizer, and it suggests me to use the `async` attribute for all CDN sources that I use, like for instance:

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To run any script I use:

```
(function(){

})();
```

I also have JavaScript code in inline `script` tags that reference such libraries. However, when I add `async` as above, I get an error in the following script:

```html
<script>
    (function(){
        jQuery.foundation();
        ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector('#app'));
    })();
</script>
```

I've tried adding `async` to this `script` tag as well, but it still doesn't work. I still get an error that the library loaded with the `async` attribute doesn't exist.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrapping your code in:

```
(function () {
})();
```

... does not delay its execution. To delay your script until resources have been loaded, wait to the [window `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload#Notes):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, ***scripts***, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

Here is an example that loads jQuery with a `<script async>` element, and shows the jQuery version via the inline script:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
});
```

```html
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To capture the event when a *particular* `async` script has been loaded, you could listen to its own `load` event. For that to work it is probably the easiest if you give an `id` to the `script` element of your interest, and make sure the inline code comes after it:

```js
jq.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
});
```

```html
<script id="jq" async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the [`async` (and `defer`) attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Properties) have no effect on inline scripts:

> The `defer` and `async` attributes must not be specified if the `src` attribute is not present.

They only have an effect on `script` elements that have the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 8):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to run inline script when the async script tag is loaded.

You can use `onload` event of the script tag.

```js
function runInline() {
  console.log('inline script run')
}
```

```html
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" onload="runInline()"></script>
```

Comment: Slightly misleading. This will fire when the entire document is loaded vs just the async script.

Comment: Pay attention to the async attribute

Comment: > The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload
This seems to suggest it does it not matter?