# Even i'm using Online CDN Jquery Script (with no inline/code) error in console as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[image]

My Script in bottom of the page just before the body is which is online CDN:

`<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">`

I also tried with:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>`

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Why these errors are occurring even i didn't add any code of my own. 
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Can you paste the full response body of the “AJAX” requests that jQuery is handling in those error call stacks? It seems most likely that either you have an error there.

Comment: You mean Output screen?

Comment: I changed my comment to ask for the response body of the AJAX requests instead of the HTML.

Comment: I'm not using any "AJAX" calls.I used this CDN to remove undefined $ error .which is for `<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(function(){
  $(".header_include").load("header.html");
 });
 $(function(){
  $(".footer_include").load("footer.html");
 });
</script>`

Comment: Try to downgrade Jquery. You can use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: errors are reduced from 10 to 2.Thank you @TanDuong ..
the remaining two errors are:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at Xb (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at y (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at c (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at Object.send (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)
    at Function.n._evalUrl (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4)`

Comment: I think there is some conflict with other library such as Bootstrap. Please give us your bootstrap version. Or you can try to use jquery 2.x https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Comment: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.3/js/tether.min.js" async></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>`
These are the CDN's now i'm using @TanDuong

Comment: Can you try to remove `async` ?

Comment: yes, even i removed the `async` no change in errors @TanDuong

Comment: I tried to use your library but It still work https://codepen.io/titan_dl_1904/pen/PRVpzj

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869839/javascript-run-inline-script-after-load-async-resources?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) link.